# Что же именно делает lock? C#

Tags: c#

Периодически сталкиваюсь с кодом вида

```
public void QueueOnMainThread(Action action)
{
    lock (actions)
    {
        actions.Add(action);
    }
}
```

`lock` закрывает лист actions от изменений и добавляет туда новое значение. Но что будет если в этот же момент в другом потоке вызовется этот код? Если `actions` уже заблокирован, то мы просто не выполним добавление нового значения, проигнорируем это? Или `lock` ждет, пока выполнится то что внутри `lock` из прошлого потока, и потом всё таки выполнит свое? Т.е. `lock` - создает и выполняет очередь.

Так что верно? `lock` - блокирует выполнение(аналог return) или ставит в очередь?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement

Comment: _`lock` ждет, пока выполнится то что внутри `lock` из прошлого потока, и потом всё таки выполнит свое_ - да.

Comment: lock - блокирует выполнение ДРУГОГО ПОТОКА до окончания работы внутри блока lock {}. То есть, если Вам так повезло, что второй поток "полез" к данным, котрые изменяются внутри блока в скобочках - то его аккуратно попросят подождать, и "отпустят", когда код в скобочках закончит работу

Comment: _`lock` закрывает лист `actions` от изменений_ - нет. В другом потоке можно без лока менять данные в этом листе сколько угодно. Один лок влияет на работу только других таких же локов, использющих один и тот же экземпляр объекта в качестве опорного.

Comment: Вообще использовать `lock` практически всегда неэффективно. Пизучайте класс `ReaderWriterLockSlim` и шаблон проектирования [Reader-Writer Lock](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8).

Comment: @aepot: RWLock (даже Slim) же вроде медленнее, чем обыкновенный lock? Надо будет попрофилировать.

Comment: @VladD странно сравнивать пефоманс совершенно по-разному работающих штук. Я говорил не про скорость реакции триггеров, а про эффективность работы решения в результате применения rw лока по сравнению с обычным.

Comment: @aepot: А, вы про семантику? Я стараюсь делать везде immutable, так что об относительной частоте Monitor vs. RWLock судить не могу.